# iPad app navigation bar with multiple buttons on the same side

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

how can I have a back button and another button both on the left side of the nav bar? since this is an ipad app there's space for multiple buttons. but I can only get it to show one button per side on the navigationitem...

Comment: If this question does not require any more attention, please delete it or mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

For people who stumbled here and were disappointed by the broken link, check out this article:

http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

Answer (score 2):

iOS now supports multiple buttons on the same side. From the **UINavigationItem** docs:

Customizing Views

```
  titleView  property
  leftBarButtonItems  property
  leftBarButtonItem  property
  rightBarButtonItems  property
  rightBarButtonItem  property
– setLeftBarButtonItems:animated:
– setLeftBarButtonItem:animated:
– setRightBarButtonItems:animated:
– setRightBarButtonItem:animated:
```

So, basically, you would write something like this to add two buttons on the left:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshPlans:)];
UIBarButtonItem *selectYearBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Year" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(selectYear)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: refreshBtn, selectYearBtn, nil];
```

Unfortunately, I haven't seen a way to do this in the Storyboard. Hope this helps.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I haven't seen a way to do this in the Storyboard." Look at my answer below. You'll see the trick I use to have it in the stroyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIBarButtonItem *btn0 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tapLevel0)];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"<2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tapLevel1:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"<3" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tapLevel2:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    space.width = 10;

    UIBarButtonItem *space2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    space2.width = 10;

  //  UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshItem)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn0, space, btn1, space2, btn2, nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

found the answer: http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/06/uibuttons-in-uinavigationbar/